# Sphere Wrapping with Three JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

By using Three JS, How can I create sphere wrapping like this- https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Sphere-Unwrapping.html for my cards. You can see my coding at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqRmrw. Right now, I can see at blank spacing, the cards are all square.

```
    var table = [
  "Screen 1", "Screen 2", "Screen 3", "Screen 4", "Screen 5", "Screen 6", "Screen 7", "Screen 8", "Screen 9"

];

var camera, scene, renderer;
var controls;

var objects = [];
var targets = {
  table: [],
  sphere: [],
  helix: [],
  grid: []
};

init();
animate();
transform(targets.sphere, 2000);

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.z = 3000;
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // table

  for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {

    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.className = 'placeholder';
    element.style.backgroundColor = 'green';

    var number = document.createElement('div');
    number.className = 'number';
    number.id = "number_" + i;
    number.textContent = i + 1;
    element.appendChild(number);

    var symbol = document.createElement('div');
    symbol.className = 'title';
    symbol.textContent = table[i];
    element.appendChild(symbol);

    var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject(element);

    scene.add(object);

    objects.push(object);

  }

  var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
  for (var i = 0, l = objects.length; i < l; i++) {

    var phi = Math.acos(-1 + (2 * i) / l);
    var theta = Math.sqrt(l * Math.PI) * phi;

    var object = new THREE.Object3D();

    object.position.x = 800 * Math.cos(theta) * Math.sin(phi);
    object.position.y = 800 * Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi);
    object.position.z = 800 * Math.cos(phi);

    vector.copy(object.position).multiplyScalar(4);

    object.lookAt(vector);

    targets.sphere.push(object);

  }

  renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  //

  controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.rotateSpeed = 1;
  controls.minDistance = 500;
  controls.maxDistance = 6000;
  controls.addEventListener('change', render);

  //

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

}

function transform(targets, duration) {

  TWEEN.removeAll();

  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {

    var object = objects[i];
    var target = targets[i];

    new TWEEN.Tween(object.position)
      .to({
        x: target.position.x,
        y: target.position.y,
        z: target.position.z
      }, Math.random() * duration + duration)
      .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut)
      .start();

    new TWEEN.Tween(object.rotation)
      .to({
        x: target.rotation.x,
        y: target.rotation.y,
        z: target.rotation.z
      }, Math.random() * duration + duration)
      .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut)
      .start();

  }

  new TWEEN.Tween(this)
    .to({}, duration * 1000000)
    .onUpdate(render)
    .start();

}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  render();

}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  TWEEN.update();
  controls.update();

}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Comment: You want to bend the rectangles? You can't do that with `CSS3DRenderer`.

Comment: The example is done with the shader. There are two sets of precomputed positions, which you can treat as two different meshes/geometries. One is a flattened plane or the UV mapping, the other is the actual sphere. Each vertex holds both of these points, and he can easily lerp between the two. 

Since you are doing something a bit different, i think you need to first generate your sphere positions the way you want them. Then unwrap them into a 2d grid so they dont randomly fly around, and then lerp.

Comment: @WestLangley - Which one is better to do?

Comment: @pailhead thanks! I am doing with that code to have each block have different ID to b assign. If i do one flattened plane, it is not going to work for me.

Comment: It appears you need to use `WebGLRenderer` to do what you want.